# How to extract and parse CSS from HTML page in Java?

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I want to extract/parse the body of HTML pages. To do so, I use the Jsoup API: https://jsoup.org/.

However, I also want to extract the CSS, but how to do it when it is in a different folder ?

My code so far is writing the code of the page in a tempFile, so I now need to get the CSS of this page to apply it in this file:

```
 public File parseHtml(String url) throws IOException {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element body = doc.body();
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(suffix, prefix);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    writer.write(body.outerHtml());
    writer.close();
    return tempFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the individual url of the CSS File out of the script-Element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, the issue is that I cannot get that url programmatically from the first url of my website. I can only get the href but therefore, I cannot use the file.

Comment: Hm.. you can get the text of the css file into a string, create a new file and push the string into this file. now you should have a clone. this clone is on your control.